# Vanilla Spring Batch Admin and JTA - why would commits suddenly stop happening?

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-batch-admin, bitronix

I have a little app built around spring-batch and spring-batch-admim that was mostly working, then I had a facepalm moment and had to add XA transactioning to it.  No big deal, this is a common enough pattern.  As soon as I did this, commits stopped happening on any transaction manager.

The spring-batch launcher executes its work, the logs say the work was committed, but the commit never happened.

I traced through the spring code into the JDBC driver.  In the debugger, I have confirmed that the commit methods are being called all the way into the driver, but the connection protocol state has already been idled before the driver's commit method is called, so no commit is executed.  It appears that the connection is returned to the pool before the commit, in the beforeCommit trigger.

I have confirmed that the same behavior is exhibited under both the org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager with org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, and the BitronixTransactionManager with bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource

I am convinced I am missing something obvious, but I can't see what it is.  If this was normal behavior, then the product would never have worked.  Does anyone out there have any ideas?

**Pseudocode for commit from driver**

```
if (protocolstate != IDLE) {
    sendCommand(COMMIT);
}
```

**Environment:**

```
OS: Windows 7
Java: 1.8.0_25
Spring: 3.2.13-RELEASE
Spring-Batch: 3.0.2-RELEASE
Spring-batch-admin: 1.3.1-RELEASE
JDBC: postgresql 9.3-1102-jdbc41
Database: postgresql 9.4
```

**Transaction manager configuration (XML):**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" />

<!--  Bitronix Transaction Manager embedded configuration -->
<bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
    <property name="logPart1Filename" value="C:\TEMP\bit-btm1.tlog}" />
    <property name="logPart2Filename" value="C:\TEMP\bit-btm2.tlog}" />
</bean>

<!-- create BTM transaction manager -->
<bean id="BitronixTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
    class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig" destroy-method="shutdown" />

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
    depends-on="BitronixTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="BitronixTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="BitronixTransactionManager" />
</bean>  

<alias alias="transactionManager" name="jtaTransactionManager"/>
<alias alias="dataSource" name="myDataSource"/>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close" depends-on="jtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="className" value="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource" />
    <property name="uniqueName" value="maxisIlmDataSource" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30" />

    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="true"/>

    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">me</prop>
            <prop key="password">mypass</prop>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</prop>
            <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
            <prop key="portNumber">5432</prop>
            <prop key="databaseName">mydb</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Log excerpt from execution:**

```
21:48:45.929 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG b.tm.BitronixTransactionManager - begun new transaction at Wed Dec 31 22:50:41 CST 1969
21:48:45.929 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
21:48:45.929 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
21:48:45.929 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
21:48:45.929 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
21:48:45.930 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
21:48:45.930 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
21:48:45.933 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
21:48:45.935 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]
21:48:45.938 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
21:48:45.940 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
21:48:45.941 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
21:48:45.942 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
21:48:45.977 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
21:48:45.977 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]
21:48:45.980 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
21:48:45.980 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
21:48:45.980 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG b.tm.BitronixTransactionManager - committing transaction a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [737072696E672D62746D00000000010A22560000000F], status=ACTIVE, 0 resource(s) enlisted (started Wed Dec 31 22:50:41 CST 1969)
21:48:45.980 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler - cancelling transaction timeout task on a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [737072696E672D62746D00000000010A22560000000F], status=ACTIVE, 0 resource(s) enlisted (started Wed Dec 31 22:50:41 CST 1969)
...
21:48:45.981 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG b.tm.journal.TransactionLogAppender - between 52346 and 52405, writing a Bitronix TransactionLogRecord with status=COMMITTED, recordLength=51, headerLength=28, time=17441418, sequenceNumber=45, crc32=-367977821, gtrid=737072696E672D62746D00000000010A22560000000F, uniqueNames=
21:48:45.981 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG b.tm.journal.TransactionLogAppender - disk journal appender now at position 52405
21:48:45.981 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction - transaction status is changing from COMMITTING to COMMITTED - executing 0 listener(s)
21:48:45.981 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG bitronix.tm.twopc.Committer - phase 2 commit succeeded with no interested resource
21:48:45.981 [tomcat-http--10] DEBUG bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction - successfully committed a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [737072696E672D62746D00000000010A22560000000F], status=COMMITTED, 0 resource(s) enlisted (started Wed Dec 31 22:50:41 CST 1969)
```

Answer (score 0):

**What was really wrong**
In another configuration file, there was a bean of class BasicDataSource.  Some of the beans instantiated were picking up this datasource instead of the one in the transaction manager.

**How I resolved it**

Step 1: A good night's sleep

Step 2: more caffeinne

Step 3:  I tracked this down by tracing into the initialzation code and determining that a JDBCTemplate was being created that was attached to the wrong type of DataSource.  I removed the library, and hey presto Spring complainedthat it couldn't initialize the beans that were pointing to the wrong datasource.

I redefined those datasource beans with the correct classes, and all is well again.